# How to Align Div Side by Side Horizontally in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I have a markup which contains `div` with some `images` as shown. Currently each section of `div` appears vertically. But, i want to show the items on left & text on right as shown in screen dump.

HTML Markup:

```
     <div id="divgetpaidnow" style="float:none;width:200px;" class="paymentclass" paytype="GetPaidNow"  paytypeid="1">
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" src="images/getpaidnow.jpg" runat="server" class="paymentimg" />
   <div>
  </div>
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rdo1" Text="Get Paid Now" runat="server" class="myradio" GroupName="rdoPaymentgroup" />
 <div class="payTypeFooterText" style="float:none;">                                                   <strong>Get Paid Now:</strong><br />
   Instant Cash, visit one of our Mall Locations and get Paid Today
  </div>
 </div>
  <div id="divamazon" style="float: none;" class="paymentclass" paytype="Amazon" paytypeid="2">
     <asp:Image ID="Image2" src="images/amazon.jpg" runat="server" class="paymentimg" />
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
       </div>
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rdo2" Text="Recommended" runat="server" class="myradio" GroupName="rdoPaymentgroup" />
      <div class="payTypeFooterText">
    <strong>Amazon Gift Card:</strong><br />
     Get paid quickly via electronic gift card and receive an extra 5%</div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.payTypeFooterText
        {
            width: 120px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

.myradio
        {
            color: grey;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Just these two `css` other `class` names are used for accessing elements using `JQUERY`.
[image: Screen Dump]

Help Appreciated!

Comment: Show us CSS also. Or make an example on fiddle.

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff i have added css please check the post..!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VeajA/2/ hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

You can use css property **float**  to align content on pages

```
<div>
    <div style='float:left;'>
        ----content---
    </div>
    <div style='float:right;'>
        ----content---
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I love Q&A's like these because it reminds people your low stack rep doesn't mean you're of low experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have a common class for all the divs and use `display:inline-block`

```
div{
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ACAKEYE/2/)**

Comment: sorry this is not what i am looking for..! please see the image ..!i need image and radiobuttin on left & text on right..!